# Pasting over existing code in jupyter lab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, copy-paste, jupyter-lab

I recently switched to jupyter lab. In a regular notebook, say I want to copy a bit of code and paste it over some existing code in the same or different cell without first manually erasing the second bit of code- I'm typically able to highlight over the bit I don't want and paste the new bit directly over it.

In jupyter lab, nothing happens when I do that. I can only paste where there is a blank space (between words, end of line, beginning of line, etc.) but not over the piece I want to get rid of. I'm also not able to paste between an empty bracket or parentheses.

I'm not able to find anything in the settings that seems related to this. Is this a jupyter lab thing and if so, is there a way to change it?

I'm using jupyterlab desktop if thats relevant